# iOS Safari 15 how to remove the spacing at top and bottom of a webpage

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari, ios15

As the title says, there are always spaces above and below the page. The following is the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hellow World!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fad0c4 99%, #fad0c4 100%);
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

The screenshot device is iPhone 12.

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Inspector]

Answer (score -1):

But it's works perfectly in IOS 10 AND IOS 11

try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">

html {
padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}

body{
margin-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
}
```